# Border set in vmin unit causes gap

Tags: css

**DESCRIPTION**

I have a weird bug where the border causes a small gap between the content and the border itself when set using `vmin` units.

**REPRODUCIBLE SNIPPET**

*resize the window to see it, as it only happens on some device viewports*

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border-right: 1vmin solid red;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content" />
</div>
```

**PREMISES**

- I'm setting border with `vmin` unit to keep it consistent between any screen resolution
- Elements should keep current structure (border on parent, background on child)
- Both elements should have `display: flex`

**PROBLEM**

I suspect the problem stands on how the `vmin` value is being rounded into pixels, creating that additional pixel which can be seen in similar scenarios (where a child with the background highlights the gap).

**WHAT I TRIED**

- By having `display: table`s instead of `flex` fixes the extra px, but this can't be an option as flex is needed
- `vw` / `vh` or any viewport unit generate the same issue

**SOLUTION**

- A solution for having a flexible border could be to simply set the `.container:after` with a `width` in percentage, `height` to 100% and a `background-color` instead of the `border`. This solution works perfectly fine, but it's not a scalable solution in case we require more than just a single border side (e.g. `border-right`).

**CONCLUSION**

So premised all this, is there perhaps some trick that can be applied directly to the border (or its element) to get around it?

I'm not concerned about finding the first solution that works; As presented, a solution exists already, so the question is based out of mere curiosity for writing better code.

Comment: You should google subpixel rendering in CSS. There are a host of articles and stack overflow questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `box-shadow` instead.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  box-shadow: 1vmin 0 0 0 #f00;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content" />
</div>
```

`box-shadow: 1vmin 0 0 0 #f00;` for right border, `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1vmin #f00;` for full border.

---

**EDIT:**

Why the gap is disappear? I think it is because box-shadow is kind of background with some offset. So, the decimal pixel is on the end. *I guess*.

[image: img]

But keep in mind that it will act different as being said by [@doğukan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10698741/do%c4%9fukan) in the comment.

> but box-shadow doesn't work like border. see the difference. with border: i.stack.imgur.com/gqgsD.png box-shadow: i.stack.imgur.com/2ZsrA.png if this is not a problem, box-shadow works fine.

Comment: Incredibly smart way of displaying a border in an alternative yet compatible way, love it!

Comment: Do you perhaps have a reason why the shadow and border approach the unit differently?

Comment: but box-shadow doesn't work like border. see the difference. with border: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqgsD.png box-shadow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZsrA.png if this is not a problem, box-shadow works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just set a background to `.container`?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: black;
  border-right: 1vmin solid red;
  border-left: 1vmin solid green;
  border-top: 1vmin solid blue;
  border-bottom: 1vmin solid orange;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content" />
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is just covering the problem, not solving it, but you're making a good point since it works perfectly fine for this use case. Not a working solution to adopt in case of multiple `.container` childrens with different backgrounds though